# Rounding of $2-10^{20}$ in IEEE double precision

Tags: rounding

How do we get the rounding of $2-10^{20}$ in IEEE double precision? The textbook says it is $-10^{20}$, but I do not know why. I think my textbook only explains the rule for rounding mantissa.

Answer (score 1):

Determine the binary exponent of $10^{20}$. From that determine the value of the lowest bit of the mantissa of $10^{20}$. Then ask yourself: How large does a number x have to be at least so that round (x-$10^{20}$) is not $-10^{20}$?